# Wifi extender connecting directly to the ethernet port

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, wifi-transfer

I just moved in to a new apartment and the apartment has an ethernet port to access the internet (router should be somewhere in the building). Every time i plug my computer to the ethernet port it asks for credentials before allowing me to access the internet. My question is, if i use a wifi extender which i could directly connect to the ethernet port in the apartment, would there be any problem when connecting to the internet (as i said before it asks for me to enter my credentials every time i connect my laptop to the port.)

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it forces you to enter credentials every time you connect, then you may not be able to plug the extender directly into the outlet, because it won't have any way to authenticate itself.

One solution is to talk to the building manager/landlord and see if they can add your extender to the router as a white-listed device.  Depending on how the router is configured, they may be able to reserve an IP address or assign a static one for your extender.  If you're a permanent resident there, I would hope they wouldn't make you enter credentials each time you hook into the Ethernet port.

If that's not a possibility, another option would be to get a Raspberry Pi or other small-footprint microcomputer, plug that into the Ethernet port, and connect the extender to that computer.  That way, you can connect a monitor and keyboard to the computer once to enter the required credentials, then just remove the monitor and keyboard and leave the Pi/Omega2/whatever connected and let the extender remain plugged in that way.